# How to write a program for multiplication table PL/SQL ask the user input a number

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-package

How to write a program for multiplication table PL/SQL ask the user input a number

this is the code display just table without input

```
Declare
    i NUMBER:=0;
    x NUMBER;
    Begin
    loop 
  i :=   i+1;
 x :=2*i;     
    dbms_output.put_line('2'||'x'||i||'='||x);
    IF i >=10 THEN
    EXIT ;
    END IF;
    END loop;
    END;
    /
```

Comment: What are you using as a client ? sql developer ? sql cl ? apex sql workshop ?

Answer (score 1):

A simple option (ran in SQL*Plus) is

```
SQL> set ver off
SQL> begin
  2    for i in 1 .. 10 loop
  3      dbms_output.put_line(&&par_number|| ' x ' || i ||' = '|| &&par_number * i);
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /
Enter value for par_number: 2
2 x 1 = 2
2 x 2 = 4
2 x 3 = 6
2 x 4 = 8
2 x 5 = 10
2 x 6 = 12
2 x 7 = 14
2 x 8 = 16
2 x 9 = 18
2 x 10 = 20

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

As Koen commented, depending on a client, substitution variable (`&&par_number`) might need to be modified to a bind variable (`:par_number`), or you'd enter it into a page item, or some other option.

More info you provide, better answer you get.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the complete multiplication table with just sql and then select whatever you want without using PL/SQL ...
Here is the code: (all ran in SQL Developer)

```sql
WITH
    nums AS
        (
            Select LEVEL "N" From Dual Connect By LEVEL <= 10
        ),
    tbl AS
        (
            Select  COL_N * N1 "N1", COL_N * N2 "N2",  COL_N * N3 "N3", COL_N * N4 "N4", COL_N * N5 "N5", 
                    COL_N * N6 "N6", COL_N * N7 "N7", COL_N * N8 "N8", COL_N * N9 "N9", COL_N * N10 "N10"
            From    (   SELECT  n2.N "COL_N",n1. N "N", n1.N "ROW_N"
                        FROM    nums n1
                        INNER JOIN nums n2 ON(1 = 1)
                    )
                        PIVOT ( MAX(N) FOR ROW_N IN(1 "N1", 2 "N2", 3 "N3", 4 "N4", 5 "N5", 6 "N6", 7 "N7", 8 "N8", 9 "N9", 10 "N10")   )
            Order By COL_N
        )
```

... the content is

```sql
SELECT N1 "1", N2 "2", N3 "3", N4 "4", N5 "5", N6 "6", N7 "7", N8 "8", N9 "9", N10 "10" FROM tbl

         1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9         10
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9         10 
         2          4          6          8         10         12         14         16         18         20 
         3          6          9         12         15         18         21         24         27         30 
         4          8         12         16         20         24         28         32         36         40 
         5         10         15         20         25         30         35         40         45         50 
         6         12         18         24         30         36         42         48         54         60 
         7         14         21         28         35         42         49         56         63         70 
         8         16         24         32         40         48         56         64         72         80 
         9         18         27         36         45         54         63         72         81         90 
        10         20         30         40         50         60         70         80         90        100
```

... and select with variable passed to:

```sql
SELECT  LPAD(N1, 2, ' ') || '  x ' || LPAD(&&M_NUM, 2, ' ') || ' = ' || LPAD(N1 * &&M_NUM, 3, ' ')  "RESULTS" 
FROM tbl        

-- with &&M_NUM = 6 results:
RESULTS      
--------------
 1  x  6 =   6 
 2  x  6 =  12 
 3  x  6 =  18 
 4  x  6 =  24 
 5  x  6 =  30 
 6  x  6 =  36 
 7  x  6 =  42 
 8  x  6 =  48 
 9  x  6 =  54 
10  x  6 =  60
```

... Or you could get the results in one row (it's 6 again)

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE N1 = &&M_NUM

        N1         N2         N3         N4         N5         N6         N7         N8         N9        N10
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         6         12         18         24         30         36         42         48         54         60
```

... or in columns ...

```sql
SELECT  N1, &&M_NUM "MULTIPLYED _BY", 
        CASE &&M_NUM  WHEN 2 THEN N2
                      WHEN 3 THEN N3
                      WHEN 4 THEN N4
                      WHEN 5 THEN N5
                      WHEN 6 THEN N6
                      WHEN 7 THEN N7
                      WHEN 8 THEN N8
                      WHEN 9 THEN N9
                      WHEN 10 THEN N10
          END "RESULT"
FROM tbl 

        N1 MULTIPLYED _BY     RESULT
---------- -------------- ----------
         1              6          6 
         2              6         12 
         3              6         18 
         4              6         24 
         5              6         30 
         6              6         36 
         7              6         42 
         8              6         48 
         9              6         54 
        10              6         60
```

... or anything else you like...